# How to set a custom stylesheet for hover and pressed states

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I used this as my button `pushButton`'s stylesheet:

```css
QPushButton#pushButton {
    background-color: yellow;
}
QPushButton#pushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);     
}
QPushButton#pushButton:hover {
   background-color: rgb(224, 255, 0);
}
```

When I hover my mouse over it, it changes its color, like I expect it to, but the hover color remains even when I press the button.

I tried changing the order, but It's still the same problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can combine states, for example:

```css
QPushButton:hover:!pressed
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[QSS reference — states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states)

Answer (score 5):

CSS, and QSS (Qt Stylesheet), depends on the order of declarations. Later declarations with the same specificity will overwrite previous declarations. So, in order to have the `pressed` state take precedence, simply move it below the `hover` state.

```css
QPushButton#pushButton {
    background-color: yellow;
}

QPushButton#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(224, 255, 0);
}

QPushButton#pushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
//base stylesheet
QPushButton
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
//pressed button stylesheet
QPushButton:pressed
{
  background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);     
}
//hover stylesheet
QPushButton:hover:!pressed
{
  background-color: rgb(224, 255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the image in QPushButton:

```
QPushButton#pushButton {
     background-url(Images/image1.png);
 }
 QPushButton#pushButton:pressed {
     background-url(Images/image2.png);   
 }

 QPushButton#pushButton:hover {
      background-url(Images/image3.png);
 }
```

Comment: Why did you think the question was about background images?

Comment: This is the same stylesheet as OP's, but it sets the background image instead. This does not answer the question, I'm flagging it as such.