# How to add hovered event for QPushButton in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm creating a project in Qt Creator.

> I wanna add **hovered** event for a QPushButton which is created in *design mode*.

But when I'm clicking *go to slot* option (which shows available events) i can't see something like *hovered()*.
[that's what I can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHy3.png)

When I was searching stackoverflow for this problem I found this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161119/using-hover-and-pressed-stylesheet-qt)):

```
QPushButton#pushButton:hover {
background-color: rgb(224, 255, 0);
}
```

And my question:

> **How to implement this on Qt Creator (when the QPushButton is created in *design mode*)?**

Thanks in advance, have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `event filter`:

look at this example, I add one push button in `mainwindow.ui` and add [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) virtual function.

Don't forget that you should `installEventFilter` in your `pushButton`

in `mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

    // QObject interface

public:
    bool  eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and in `mainwindow.cpp` :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool  MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if ((watched == ui->pushButton) && (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter))
    {
        qDebug() << "Button is hovered !";
    }

    return false;
}
```

the result is :

[image]